# Jquery Dialog Box Background is not transparent

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

i have added a asp.net web form gridvIew inside a jquery dialog box, however everytime the dialog loads up the background is still visible to the user and not tranparent.

Not a front end developer however i have added all the dialog options such opacity etc...

```
$(function () {
      $("#ButtonQUEUE").click(function () {
          alert("Wednesday");
          $("#popupdiv").dialog({
              title: "Show Modal POPUP",
              width: 350,
              height: 300,
              modal: true,
              opacity: 50,
              buttons: {
                  Close: function () {

                      $(this).dialog('close');

                  }
              }



          });



      })


  });;
```

For the actual results, i would like the dialog when it loads up for the background to be transparent so the user just focus o the dialog box content

Comment: Assuming this is using the jQueryUI dialog, then you can control the opacity of the overlay by using CSS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have tried .ui-dialog trick but still nothing , do you have an example?

Comment: You probably need to make the CSS selector more specific in order to override the default styling.